# bash script assign output to a variable fail

Tags: linux, bash, shell, yocto

OS:Yocto

I want to assign the shell output to a variable,

but get the error "test.sh: line 3: out: command not found".

How to do that ...?

this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

out = "$(ls /dev/ | grep "tty" | wc -l)"
echo"$out"
```

I tried this:
[How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command)

Comment: `out="..."` - note no spaces around `=`.

Comment: @Amandan is correct. In fact, Bash even allows you to do `out="something" some-command arg1 arg2`, which will execute `some-command arg1 arg2`, with `${out}` set to `something`.

Comment: (but not set `$out` in the local process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whitespace matters.

```
#!/bin/bash

out="$(ls /dev/ | grep "tty" | wc -l)"
echo "$out"
```

Answer (score 1):

when you assign value to variable don't keep Whitespace before and after "=" that makes error in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

out="$(ls /dev/ | grep "tty" | wc -l)"
echo"$out"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try strip spaces around `=`, i.e. `out="$(ls /dev/ | grep "tty" | wc -l)"`