# =: command not found (shell)

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to make a script in the shell that executes a page's specific HTML.

However, whenever I try to set the variable to `curl https://scratch.mit.edu`, it shows =: command not found, I searched this on Google and it tells me to set the variable like this:

```
PROJECT = curl https://scratch.mit.edu
```

However, this does not meet my needs because it shows

```
PROJECT: command not found
```

So, I try this:

```
$PROJECT = curl https://scratch.mit.edu
```

It did work for clearing the variable error but then, this happens

```
=: command not found
```

EDIT: I just realized -

it should be

```
$PROJECT=curl https://scratch.mit.edu
```

but then this is what the error is:

```
Command '=curl' not found, did you mean:
   command 'curl' from snap curl (7.84.0)
   command 'curl' from deb curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.4)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for addition versions
```

What do I do?

Note that this question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174178/bash-script-assign-output-to-a-variable-fail) as I cannot use the function curl and assign the value to the variable

Comment: `PROJECT=$(curl https://scratch.mit.edu)`

Comment: Wait -- if you're not trying to assign to a variable, what _are_ you trying to do? You say directly "when I try to set the variable"; why shouldn't we believe you're trying to set a variable?

Comment: If you're trying to store _the command itself_ in the variable, read [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I tried this - PROJECT=$(curl https://scratch.mit.edu)

But now when I run echo $PROJECT, this is what it shows -
curl

Comment: It is unclear, **what** you want to achieve in the end. Do you want to store the **output of a command** in a variable, or do you want to store the textual form of the command itself in a variable? In the latter case, `PROJECT` should be an array, not a scalar.

Comment: `PROJECT=$(curl scratch.mit.edu)` stores the output of `curl`. To have the string `curl` itself stored implies that you left off the `$`; it's what you would get from `PROJECT=(curl scratch.mit.edu); echo $PROJECT`.